# Script not writing files when called from server but works when run manually

Tags: php, python, scripting, permissions

[Current folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIHsG.jpg)

I have a python script that is using PyPDF2 to merge pdfs together and output them into a different folder.
At the moment I'm trying to run it on my local machine (windows 10).

The script works fine if I run it from a terminal, the pdfs are merged and it is a sight to behold.

However when I run the script from the server, it still runs but it doesn't create the merged pdf. I know the script runs because the `$output` variable resolves as the printed name variable from the script.
The script is being called from the `Deliveries.php` file

So basically the script will run but won't write `:(`.
I'm trying to use php to run the script.

```
$command_text = 'python '.BASEPATH.'../application/controllers/scripts/merge.py';
$command = escapeshellcmd($command_text);
$output = shell_exec($command);//Returns the printed 'name' variable from the script
```

And the script is:

```
import os
import time
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

name = int(time.time())
name = str(name) + '_1.pdf'
print(name)//The returned variable
files = os.listdir("staging")

pdfs = []
for file in files:
    pdfs.append("staging/" + file)

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(open(pdf, "rb"))

with open("here/"+name, "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

I imagine it's a permissions issue, but I'm not sure how to go about resolving it.

**SOLVED**

I think it has something to do with codeigniter 3 but baiscally I had to reference the directories in relation to the root folder.

```
import os
import time
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

name = int(time.time())
name = str(name) + '_1.pdf'
# print(name)

files = os.listdir('application/controllers/scripts/staging')

pdfs = []
for file in files:
    pdfs.append("application/controllers/scripts/staging/" + file)
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(open(pdf, "rb"))
with open("../assets/pdfs/"+name, "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

Comment: How do you know the server runs it?  What are you running on?  *unix?  As what user from the terminal?  As what user by the server?  What are the permissions of the file to be written?  The directory?  Is this SELinux, with extended security policies?

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to get it to run locally (windows 10), and I know that the script runs because the $output variable resolves as the printed name variable, sorry I have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Run your server as Administrator (Windows) **OR** Run with Sudo permission (Linux). Then try

Comment: I’d write a few more output statements at later points in the script: `print(files)` in case `os.listdir` fails with an exception,  `print(pdfs)` to verify it is finding the input files, & `print("done")` to verify the script reaches the end.

Comment: Does the `here` subdirectory already exist? If not, that could cause the problem.

Comment: I've added an image of the current file structure, sorry about that. 
Prior to creating this question I had additional `print()` commands throughout the script and they all worked. The app itself is being run on xampp with admin rights.

Comment: `here` needs to be writable by the calling process.   Swap it for `/tmp` temporarily, does it then work?

Comment: Uhh it turns out I made a mistake. I tried to `print(files)` after the `files = os.listdir("staging")` and it returned a null value